# Cannot read property 'db' of undefined after defining MongoClient.connect() outside of app.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, node-mongodb-native

Previously I had a working, single-file, application that was essentially:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.set('socketio', io);

import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

var mongo_client;

var connection_string = 'mongodb://localhost:27017' // for local development environment 

MongoClient.connect(connection_string, (err, client) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    mongo_client = client;
  }
});

/*

lots of middleware and route handling

*/

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

In middleware, within the same file, I would make a call to the database with something like:

```js
var collection = mongo_client.db('users').collection('users');

var query = { };

var options = { };

  try {
    var user = await collection.findOne(query, options);
    return user;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error: ' + err);
  }
```

I'm in the process of refactoring and have put the `MongoClient.connect()` block in its own file.

`config/database.js` now looks like:

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const { connection_string } = require('./environment_variables');

let mongo_client;

MongoClient.connect(connection_string, (err, client) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    mongo_client = client;
    console.log('FIRST:  mongo_client: ');
    console.log(mongo_client);
  }
});

console.log('SECOND:  mongo_client: ');
console.log(mongo_client);

module.exports = mongo_client;
```

To begin testing how to import it into another file, I am doing this in `app.js`:

```js
const mongo_client = require('./config/database');

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const query = { username: 'my name' };
  const collection = mongo_client.db('users').collection('users');   // <----- error is here, mongo_client is undefined    
  const result = await collection.findOne(query);
  res.json({ result: result });
});
```

(note, when I better understand how all this works, I will move the `route` and `middleware` handling out of `app.js`)

The console logs are:

```
SECOND:  mongo_client:
undefined
FIRST:  mongo_client:
MongoClient {
// ... lots of mongodb client properties here  
}
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined
```

So it seems like `MongoClient.connect()` is asynchronous and therefore `mongo_client` is not defined before I try and call `mongo_client.db('users').collection('users')`.

My questions are:

- How can this issue be resolved?
- Why wasn't it happening before I extracted `MongoClient.connect()` out of `app.js`?

I've been reading articles like these:

[MongoClient connection pooling](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connection-pooling)

[MongoClient docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/classes/MongoClient.html)

But they seem to either:

- Include subsequent calls to the database within the `MongoClient.connect()` function block (and i can't wrap my whole app within that function) OR
- They call `app.listen()` within the `MongoClient.connect()` function block (and this is also not feasible as I do several things with `express()` and `http` and `socket.io`)

Environment:

```
node v14.18.1  
"mongodb": "^4.1.4" (native driver)
```

**Edit:**

I tried the following changes in `config/database.js` per [this article](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs-mongodb-how-to-get-connected-to-your-database).

I replaced this:

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const { connection_string } = require('./environment_variables');

let mongo_client;

MongoClient.connect(connection_string, (err, client) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    mongo_client = client;
  }
});
module.exports = mongo_client;
```

with this:

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const { connection_string } = require('./environment_variables');

const mongo_client = new MongoClient(connection_string);

const is_this_the_right_thing_to_do = async () => {
  await mongo_client.connect();
};

is_this_the_right_thing_to_do();

module.exports = mongo_client;
```

The error went away and it is returning a result, but I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it.

Also, I am not sure how I can use the single instance of `mongo_client` in all routes and middleware.  I tried requiring it at the top of `app.js`, hoping that the routes and middleware (in other files) that were required afterwards would have access to it, but they don't, this was the error in the route middleware:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: mongo_client is not defined
```

**Another edit:**

I've posted an answer on someone else's question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70135909) which may be what I am looking for, will update this post after further testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access database (mongo_client.db("your database name here") in your case) from other routes then you can maybe try something like this in your app.js or index.js.

```
const connectDB = async () => {
  await client.connect();
  db = client.db("greendeckData");
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.db = db;
    next();
  });
  app.use("/get", getRouter);
};
```

You can check the source from where I found the solution link, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796719/how-to-do-connection-pooling-with-nodemongo-when-routes-are-in-separate-module?noredirect=1&lq=1)